# Проблема с наследованием в Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование

Есть у меня два класса, и один является родителем, а второй - ребенком. 
Когда я пытаюсь вызвать родительский метод - получаю ошибку, что, не хватает аргумента Self.

Пример кода:

```
class Osnovnoy:
    __init__(self):
        self.data = '1100111001010'
    def method(self):
        return f'{self.data}printuem'

class Rebyonok(Osnovnoy):
    def metod(self):
        print(Osnovnoy.method())
```

Доп. пример класса ребёнка:

```
class Eto(Master):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def baloonl():
            vari = ['Yes', 'No']
            ans = random.choice(vari)
            requests.post(Master.sendMessage(), data = 'tut chto-to bilo')
```

Доп пример класса родителя:

```
class Master:
    def __init__(self):
        self.link = 'data1'
        self.data2 = 'data2'

    def sendMessage(self):
        send = f'{self.link}/sendMessage'
        return send
```

Comment: С наследственностью у питона все в порядке поверьте)

Comment: С наследственностью всё в порядке, да вот только у меня её понять не получается

Comment: Про наследственность это была шутка, просто не наследственность а наследование.

Comment: я понял :D
и спасибо, что отредактировали вопрос.

Comment: Во превых не Osnovnoy.method() а self.method()

Comment: Во вторых вы сами себя вызываете рекурсивно и ваш код упадет через кучу итераций

Comment: И почему init без def это вообще то тоже метод?

Comment: init без def - это я забыл вставить в пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Osnovnoy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = '1100111001010'
        self.xxx = None

    def method(self):
        self.xxx = "{}printuem".format(self.data)

class Rebyonok(Osnovnoy):
    def method(self):
        super().method()
        print(self.xxx)


r = Rebyonok()
r.method()
```

Comment: не помогает. возможно я расписал код не совсем корректно. сейчас отредактирую

Comment: @Gargoyle Этот код работает, я его проверил только что, я его не в воздухе писал.

Comment: я верю, но в моём коде - метод ребёнок использует метод родителя, и это вызывает ошибку. в коде, что был дан в этом вопросе - класс ребёнок не имеет доп. метода, который бы использовал метод родителя

Comment: @Gargoyle Вы не можете вне метода в классе код писать! То есть что бы в классе любом! выполнить код он должен быть в методе!

Comment: так я и не пишу код вне класса. дело в том, что класс ребёнок в своём методе использует метод родителя, и это вызывает конфликт

Comment: @Gargoyle приведите весь код.

Comment: `class Eto(Master):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def baloonl():
            vari = ['Yes', 'No']
            ans = random.choice(vari)
            requests.post(Master.sendMessage(), data = 'placeholder')`

Comment: Это что такое) ? я имел ввиду в вопросе а не в комментах и я вроде уже дал ответ

Comment: простите, обновил вопрос